# How to use Magento2 Recaptcha in GraphQl APIs

Tags: magento2, rest-api, graphql, recaptcha

I want to Use Captcha / Recaptcha in my Graphql APIs I got this link for [protected mutations](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/protected-endpoints/)

It only shows to insert it in headers but it won't do anything in Graphql apis and for rest apis it gives error of recatcha validation failed

Please guide how will i provide the value of captcha and from where i will get the these values to authorized the user ?